# Mqtt messages are not publishing to Siddhi from C

Tags: c, mqtt, paho, siddhi

I am trying to publish mqtt messages to Siddhi Stream processor. I could send the message from my C program and rc is 0. There is no connection issue but the message is not published to Siddhi.

My C Code to publish mqtt messages is:

```
#define ADDRESS     "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "mqttClient"
#define TOPIC       "mqttTopic"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         0
#define TIMEOUT     30000L

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
MQTTClient client;
MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
int rc;
int success;

MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 60;
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts);

if (rc!= MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if(rc == 0){
    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen("hello");
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    success=MQTTClient_publish(client,TOPIC,pubmsg.payloadlen,"hello",pubmsg.qos,pubmsg.retained,NULL);  
    printf("%d\n", success); 
}
//MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
if(rc==0){
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
}else{
    printf("Message not delivered");
}
MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
return rc;
}
```

I don't understand what is the mistake iam making. Any suggestion would really help me.

Comment: When you connect to the broker, the broker will only issue you with notifications when new data for the topics you have subscribed to arrive, so if nothing is updating the broker will send you nothing.

Comment: @SPlatten you mean to try to send different data each time right. I tried doing it. It didn't work out actually.Actually the data is being sent but not published at siddhi

Comment: no I didn't, MQTT there are two parts to it, a Broker which has topics and subscribers.  You are a subscriber, when the broker receives an update to a topic, any subscribers to that topic are notified of the new data.